# Using Mediawiki to store data

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm trying to write an small application where people can define their structure or the hierarchy of anything. I was thinking of leveraging Mediawiki for this and using this for backend and on the front end, I Was planning to use either jQuery or something else, which can communicate with MediaWiki. Do you think that it's possible to do using MediaWiki?

Thanks

Comment: yes\no\maybe - based on the information provided pick one randomly.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using MediaWiki to store data is a **really bad idea**.  Wikis are meant for loosely structured text, and trying to improve a rigid hierarchy on them leads to endless pain -- parsing MediaWiki markup alone is a nightmare.

Comment: You are right. We will also have unstructured data.The whole point is to leverage what MEdia Wiki provides. For example, if I have to implement revisions or changes to that data, it would be very difficult to do that.So I'm trying to leverage what Wikis provide.

Comment: Semantic MediaWiki is pretty good at storing certain kinds of data. Anyway, the question contains way too little information to understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [ContentHandler](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Manual:ContentHandler) now.